# sql after insert trigger error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I have to check specific keyword's weight and force those which have weight > 3 to 3. It's my very first time I work with triggers, this is my code but it doesn't work, why?

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `elections`.`keyword_AFTER_INSERT`
    AFTER INSERT ON `keyword`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        if(weight > 3) then begin
        set weight = 3;
        end;
        end if;
    END
```

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? (This doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Besides, AFTER insert it's too late. Do before!

Comment: What error you were getting would have been a useful piece of info as well...

Comment: Whatever it is, it's not sql server...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where the delimiter has been put. Several changes has been made and I'm not sure what you mean with 'elections':

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `keyword_AFTER_INSERT`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `keyword`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

        IF NEW.weight > 3 then
            set NEW.weight = 3;
        END IF;

    END;
```